# jquery scrollTop animation function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have written my jQuery code which is supposed to create a fadeIn on scroll animation to my element. But the element does not reveal on scroll. Please does anyone have an idea what may be wrong with my code? here's my code below:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();

        var windowScrollPosTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        var windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;

    jQuery.fn.revealOnScroll = function() {

        return this.each(function() {

        var objectOffset = jQuery(this).offset();
        var objectOffsetTop = objectOffset.top;

        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("hidden")){

            jQuery(this).css("opacity", 0).addClass("hidden");

        }


        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("animation-complete")) {

            if (windowScrollPosBottom > objectOffsetTop) {
                jQuery(this).animate({"opacity": 1}, 
                3000).addClass("animation-complete");
            }
        }

        });

    } // end function here

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();

        windowScrollPosTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;

        jQuery(".tg-whychooseus").revealOnScroll();

     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems to work (although I would review it's efficiency) if you remove references to the "hidden" class and start with something like this (I've given the style inline but css is probably better):

```
<div class="tg-whychooseus" style="opacity:0">WHY CHOOSE US ?</div>
```

If you add a `".hidden"` class that has a `"display:none;"` attribute, the animation runs, but the element is still `"display:none;"`because of this class, which is probably why the element does not reveal (I'm guessing because you haven't given the html or the css).

Good luck with the plugin (consider "throttling" at least to avoid continuous triggering of onScroll, and try to make sure you are not assigning variable values unnecessarily if all the elements have class "animation-complete") and I hope this helps.

(ps there is an article on "throttling" here [How to Throttle Scroll Events](https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/))

(pps I've rehashed your code to give a different approach to make it work (but I'm sure it can be made more efficient, and I haven't tested the logic for showing multiple divs - you can maybe look at that). I would recommend going through it, and reference some other code you can find trying to do the same thing, and, there's no real shortcut, you'll probably need to put in some time to understand the sometimes subtle concepts of plugins. It's not always straightforward, and as ever, it's usually best to start very simple and build from there. There are resources on the web but they're pretty fragmented).

Html:

```
<div class="tg-whychooseus" style="opacity:0;">WHY CHOOSE US ?</div>
```

Script (with comments):

```
// Function invoked immediately
!function () {
    // Put any code here for before document.ready

    // When document ready
    $(function () {
        // Get collection of revealItems
        var revealItems = $(".tg-whychooseus");
        // Adjust revealItems when document.ready, before scrolling
        // (Not sure why you need this - why not hard code this in to html?)
        $.each(revealItems, function () {
            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
                jQuery(this).css("opacity", 0).addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
        // Whenever there is a scroll event
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            // You should consider "throttling" these events
            // to kick in shortly after a scroll event has completed
            // rather than continuously => logic here not checked
            var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
            var windowScrollPosTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;
            // Iterate through the collection of revealItems
            revealItems.each(function () {
                if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("animation-complete")) {
                    // When to animate logic (not tested), and note you've incurred overhead just to get to this point for each scroll event
                    var objectOffset = jQuery(this).offset();
                    var objectOffsetTop = objectOffset.top;
                    if (windowScrollPosBottom > objectOffsetTop) {
                        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("animation-complete")) {
                            // Animate
                            $(this).animate({
                                opacity: 1
                            }, 3000, function () {
                                // When animation is complete
                                $(this).addClass("animation-complete");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but i've tried this same solution but to no avail. I had tried the animation earlier which worked but to avoid repetition of code, i decided to wrap it into a function so i can call it at any time i wish and in turn use that same animation on other elements on my page. That's when i encountered the problem and element did not reveal on scroll.

Comment: I was guessing as to your css and html. I've updated the answer to give something with comments that works on my machine which I hope gives you something to work with and build on :-)

Comment: And if you're looking for a plugin approach to attach to elements, have a look at this plugin boilerplate (there are plenty of others out there, but this is as good a starting point as any) - http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

Comment: In fact i'm so grateful for your help. Yeah the animation works now. Thanks man!!!!

Comment: Yey nice one and good - and really glad to help - you could mark the answer as answered and give it an upvote if you're feeling generous so I can scramble some points heh :-)

Comment: Sure thing! Say no more. Thanks brother!

Comment: What's your twitter ID? Let me follow you so we can connect better!